# How do I use an UpdateView to update a Django Model?

Tags: django, view

I'm trying to update a model in Django using the class-based generic view UpdateView.

I read the page [Updating User model in Django with class based UpdateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181041/updating-user-model-in-django-with-class-based-updateview) to try and get me started, but I'm getting an error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'id'

I'm a fresh face to Django, so please be forgiving if I'm doing something stupid.

//urls.py

```
url(r'^portfolios/update/(?P<id>\d+)/$',PortfoliosUpdateView.as_view()),
```

//views.py

```
class PortfoliosUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = PortfoliosCreateForm
    model = Portfolios
    template_name = 'portfolios/create.html'

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.object = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.request.id)
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object, form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.request.id)
        return obj
```

It's mostly just a modified version of the code originally posted, but I thought it'd work. I know that I'm trying to retrieve the id passed as a GET parameter, but that doesn't seem to come through in the request variable. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks

Edit: I think I fixed it, but this may be wrong:
I changed the lines

```
self.object = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.request.id)
obj = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.request.id)
```

to

```
self.object = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
obj = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
```

I could be wrong.

Comment: Your update does fix the original bug correctly. I don't see why you need to override the ``get`` method though, looks like that's what ``UpdateView`` does under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should be:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = Portfolios.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
    return obj
```

Look at class based generic view dispatch explains that keyword arguments are assigned to self.kwargs.:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
    # request method isn't on the approved list.
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    self.request = request
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've simplified my code significantly.

Answer (score 7):

`id = self.request.GET.get('id',None)` is what you needed when trying to access the GET query string.

However, your view can be simplified:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from yourapp.models import Portfolios
from yourapp.forms import PortfoliosCreateForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^portfolios/update/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', UpdateView.as_view(
        model=Portfolios,
        form_class=PortfoliosCreateForm,
        template_name='portfolios/create.html',
        success_url='/portfolios'
    ), name='portfolio_update'),
)
```

Comment: I prefer wrapping my views in `myapp.views`. E.g. in `myapp.views`: `portfolio_update = UpdateView.as_view(...)`, then in the urlconf I only need to type `url(r'pattern', "myapp.views.portfolio_update", name="portfolio_update")`. Does not fit every purpose, but I find it cleaner for most of my views.

Comment: While this is a totally valid solution, best Django practices suggest keeping that logic for views.py instead of in the url pattern. -- From Two Scoops of Django

Comment: There is no logic in the snippet I posted. @JacobValenta

Comment: I meant logic as in the model, form_class, template_name and success url, CBV are just that, class based Views, and the best way to implement them (from Two Scoops of Django) are .as_view()

Comment: The way I do it is I add this to just below where the view is defined in views.py, my_view = login_required(MyView.as_view()), then in my urls.py: urlpatterns = patterns('my_app.views',
                       url(r'^my_view_url/$', 'my_view', name='my_view'), )

Comment: @BurhanKhalid shouldn't the regex be `(?P<pk>\d+)/$`. Your regex would also match a slug

Comment: Using the verb `update` (or any verb like `create`, `get`, etc.) in the URL isn't a best practice for ReSTful web sevices.

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ModelName  # required
    template_name = 'x/h1.html'
    form_class = ModelNameForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app:page1')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optional condition to restrict what users can see
        """
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(id__lt=20)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy(
            'app1:abc',
            kwargs={'pk': self.object.id}
        )
```

**urls.py**

In `urlpatterns=[]`

```
path('xyz/<pk>/', MyUpdateView.as_view(),name='xyz')
```

**my_model_view.html**

```
{{form}}
```

You will be able to edit `ModelName` at url `/xyz/<pk>/` where `<pk>` can be anything from 1 to 20 based on our condition in `get_queryset()`. Take that condition out to allow users to edit any object.

`self.object` is only available after post request to the UpdateView.