# How to display a date attribute of an object as the default value in HTML date input type

Tags: html, django, django-models

Hi I am trying to implement a editing page that accept the id of an object and load all its original value && enable editing/updateing. 
e.g

for text type ,I use

```
<label>Field1:</label>
     <input type="text" id="id_field1" value='{{ objectInstance.filed1}}' name="field1"/>
```

for Textares

```
<label>Field2:</label>
    <textarea id="id_field2" name="field2">
        {{ objectInstance.field2}}
```

They both worked fine in loading original data of the instance and allowing editing. But for the date field, I cannot find out how to load it..
I am trying something like

```
<label>Deadline:</label>
            <input type="date" id="id_deadline" name="deadline" value={{objectInstance.deadline}}>
```

(the deadline is of date data type e.g 2013-6-4)

Can anyone help solving this problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: You mean you want date field in your page?? If yes why don't you use jquery.

Comment: yea,initially there is a input type of type="date" so I just used it,now I find it difficult to load some date data and display it as default value.

Comment: @MayankJain Is three any way to do this? or I am already in the wrong direction and display a default value is not possible here. Thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) generic class based view to simplify this process. A similar question was [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271757/how-do-i-use-an-updateview-to-update-a-django-model).

The other way to fix this is to use a `ModelForm`, and pre-load it with an instance. This is actually what `UpdateView` does, but if you don't want to use class based views, here is the alternative:

In your `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from someapp.models import SomeModel

class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

In your `views.py`:

```
def someview(request):
    obj = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)  # Fetch the object to be edited
    form = SomeModelForm(instance=obj) # Load the form with the object's data
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'form': form})
```

In `edit.html`:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token $}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will automatically create the form, fill it in with the data from the model. You would still have to write the logic to update the record in your view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really very short code! letting the framework handles it. thanks a lot