# Getting a NoReverseMatch error even though my 'Identity_nest_list' uniform resource locator contains the pk parameter

Tags: python, django

I am attempt to update an instance and return to the Template view of the instance.

Problem : The code renders the edit view however when I edit the instance and press save it returns this error. I realize that the error is telling my that my `Identity_nest_list` URL doesn't havea pk parameter. However I added it and it is still giving me the error.

Essentially I want to be able to edit the object, save the edit and redirect the user to the updated version of the Identity_unique instance, along with the other instances that are already there

[image]

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/nesting/Identity-edit/L882394/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=umHqs06uQmn0fsBNPjnqpuv4yyBIPkGGJNmN1l83TLUSVFh3ja1WPd8reE3IvSEX

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.5.3
Installed Applications:
['Identities',
 'nesting',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'Identity.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  240.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  163.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  79.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  147.         if self.success_url:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __wrapper__
  111.                 res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /nesting/Identity-edit/L882394/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'Identity_nest_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

> Here is the code :

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView
from nesting.forms import Identity_Form, Symptom_Form
from nesting.models import Identity_unique, Symptom_relation
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy



class Identity_view(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'nesting/nesting.html'

    def get(self, request):


        form = Identity_Form()

        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user)

        var = {'form': form, 'Identities': Identities}

        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

    def post(self, request):



        form  = Identity_Form(request.POST)

        content = None

        if form.is_valid():

            NIS = form.save(commit = False)
            NIS.user = request.user
            NIS.save()


            content = form.cleaned_data['NIS']

            form = Identity_Form()


            return redirect('nesting:nesting')

        var = {'form': form, 'content': content}

        return render(request,self.template_name, var)





class Identity_nest_list_view(TemplateView):



    model = Identity_unique

    template_name = 'nesting/Identity_nest.html'


    def get(self, request):

        form = Identity_Form()

        Identities = Identity_unique.objects.filter(user = request.user).order_by('-Timestamp')
        var = {'form':form, 'Identities': Identities}
        return render(request, self.template_name, var)

class Identity_unique_Update(UpdateView):

    model = Identity_unique

    fields = [ 'first_Name', 'last_Name', 'location', 'date_of_birth', 'contact',]

    success_url = reverse_lazy('Identity_nest_list')
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from nesting.views import Identity_view, Identity_nest_list_view, Symptoms_document_view, Medical_History_nest_view, Identity_unique_Update
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
                    url(r'^$', Identity_view.as_view(), name = 'nesting'),
                    url(r'^Identity-nest/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Identity_nest_list_view.as_view(), name = 'Identity_nest_list'),
                    url(r'^Symptoms-document/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Symptoms_document_view.as_view(), name = 'Symptoms_nest_list'),
                    url(r'^Symptom-view/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Medical_History_nest_view.as_view(), name = 'Medical_History_nest'),
                    url(r'^Identity-edit/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Identity_unique_Update.as_view(), name = 'Identity_unique_view_update')

]
```

***Identity_nest.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    {% block head %}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>See patient</title>
  </head>

  {% endblock %}
  <body>


{% block body %}

<div class = "row" style = "margin-top: 80px;">

  <div class="col-sm" >

      <nav class =" "  >

        <ul class = "nav flex-column">

                         <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{% url 'nesting:nesting'%}" ><small>Create  Identity </small></a></li>

                         <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "#"><small>Move to Trash</small> </a></li>
          </ul>

      </nav>
  </div>

  <div class = "col-sm" >

{% for Identity in Identities %}

    <div class = "card " style = "margin-top: 20px;" >

            <ul class = "list-group list-group-flush">
               <li class = "list-group-item"> <small class = "text-muted">Created On : {{Identity.Timestamp}}</small></li>

              <li class = "list-group-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{% url 'nesting:Medical_History_nest' Identity.pk %}" >{{Identity.first_Name}}  {{Identity.last_Name}} </a> <p>NIS:  {{ Identity.NIS }}</p></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><p> <small>Contact: {{ Identity.contact}}</small></p></a></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><p> <small>Birthday: {{ Identity.date_of_birth}}</small></p></a></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{%url 'nesting:Symptoms_nest_list' Identity.pk %}" ><small>Create Medical State </small></a></li>
              <li class = "list-group-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{%url 'nesting:Identity_unique_view_update' Identity.pk %}" ><small>Update</small></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
          {% endfor %}
  </div>

<div class="col-sm" ></div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

***Identity_unique_form.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}


<html>

    <head>


       {% block head %}

    <title>Update</title>

    {% endblock %}



    </head>

    <body>

    {% block body %}

    <style media="screen">
      #navigation {
      margin-top: 90px;

      }

    </style>

    <div class = "container">

            <div class = "row">
                                <nav class="col-md-3"  style="  margin-top: 90px;">

                                  <ul class = "nav flex-column">
                                                    <li class = "nav-item"> <a class = "nav-link"  href = "{% url 'nesting:nesting'%}"><small>Create Identity</small> </a></li>
                                                   <li class = "nav-item"><a class = "nav-link" href = "{% url 'nesting:Identity_nest_list'%}" ><small>See  Identity </small></a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </nav>

            <main class = "col-md-7"  style="  margin-top: 180px;">

                      <form method = 'post' novalidate>

                        {% csrf_token %}

                        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                                      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                                          {{ error }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                      </div>
                          {% endif %}




                                    <div class = "form-row">

                                      <div class = "form-group col-md-6">

                                        {{form.NIS.errors}}
                                        {{form.NIS}}

                                      </div>

                                      <div class = "form-group col-md-6">

                                        {{form.contact.errors}}
                                        {{form.contact}}

                                      </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class = "form-row">

                                      <div class = "form-group col-md-6">

                                        {{form.first_Name.errors}}
                                        {{form.first_Name}}

                                      </div>

                                      <div class = "form-group col-md-6">

                                        {{form.last_Name.errors}}
                                        {{form.last_Name}}

                                      </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class = "form-row">

                                      <div class = "form-group col-md-6">

                                        {{form.location.errors}}
                                        {{form.location}}

                                      </div>

                                        <div class = "form-group col-md-6">

                                          {{form.date_of_birth.errors}}
                                          {{form.date_of_birth}}

                                        </div>

                                    </div>


<button class = "btn-primary btn-large btn ">Submit</button>

 </form>

</div>
</main>
            </div>

    {% endblock %}



  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Success url of Identity_unique_Update does not contain pk:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('Identity_nest_list')
```

Change it to:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('nesting:Identity_nest_list', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: What does XXX mean?

Comment: it means self.object.pk

Comment: Am I to import a `self` because I am getting this error 

`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: I made the edit but each time I attempted to submit the edit it gives me `NoReverseMatch at /nesting/Identity-edit/L882394/
Reverse for 'Identity_nest_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 'L882394'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` 

Here is my public repo if you are interested : https://github.com/iivri/Nesting/tree/master/Identity

Comment: do you use namespace?

Comment: Yes I do use namespace to improve the url constructions

Comment: the code in the repo is different from your question url(r'^Identity-nest/$', Identity_nest_list_view.as_view(), name = 'Identity_nest_list'),

Comment: Yes sorry about that I made an edit test something. I still got the error.

Comment: if you are using namespace nesing, then try to change to reverse('nesting:Identity_nest_list', ...)

Comment: Should I return the regex to 

`url(r'^Identity-nest/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Identity_nest_list_view.as_view(), name = 'Identity_nest_list')`?  

If so, I got the page not found error when I did that. If not that I got this : 

`NoReverseMatch at /nesting/Identity-edit/L882394/
Reverse for 'Identity_nest_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 'L882394'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['nesting/Identity-nest/$']`

Comment: one more step and you will solve the problem. Have a look at last line - the url is found, you are giving pk to it...but actually url doesn't formated to accept pk. Do it and it will work

Comment: here is the correct line url(r'^Identity-nest/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', Identity_nest_list_view.as_view(), name = 'Identity_nest_list'), just put it back to the project

Comment: I seemed to have solved the NoReverseMatch error but I am now getting this error : 

`Page not found (404)`
`Request Method: GET`
`Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/nesting/Identity-edit/L882394/None`

Comment: you have to continue programming UpdateView. It is already different question and not related to the question. Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271757/how-do-i-use-an-updateview-to-update-a-django-model

Comment: Unfortunately I am having difficulty understanding the code in that link but I will read it until I do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also have a look at Django documentation and relevant info in Internet. Hope it helps!

Comment: I will!. I may post the `page not found` problem also to see if I can get some help. Thank you again!