# Django UpdateView without pk in url

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

Is it possible eliminate `pk` from url related to `UpdateView`?

For example, if I have

```
url(r'^myobj/update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.UpdateMyObj.as_view(), name="update")
```

is there any way to write it like

```
url(r'^myobj/update/$', views.UpdateMyObj.as_view(), name="update")
```

and then send `pk` as a parameter in `POST` or `GET` request?

Comment: For a shorter alternative to this answer see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181041/updating-user-model-in-django-with-class-based-updateview

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes it is possible you just need to override the `get_object` method:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class UpdateMyObj(UpdateView):
    # .....

    def get_object(self):
        return MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('pk')) # or request.POST
```

Comment: Have you a Link with implementation? Thanks

Comment: It is makes sense to use get_object_or_404 to get object

Comment: Best practice is to not use `request.GET` for updates on the server. It's best to always use `request.POST` instead.

Comment: @Semmel That `request.GET` is referring to a `get` request made to the server. Not the method the OP is using to update the database records.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it works like this

```
class MyViewUpdate(UpdateView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(my_id_or_name_of_field=self.kwargs['pk_or_field_name']) # instead of self.request.GET or self.request.POST
        return obj
```

Comment: Shadowing keywords is horrible - never use `object` as a variable name!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying