# Django 1.8 UpdateView generates 405 error and blank template

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, http-status-code-405

I am new to Python and Django, so please bear with me! I am coding with Django 1.8 and Python 3.

I have the following view:

```
class UpdatePart(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'maketen/update_part.html'
    model = Part
    form_class = EditPartForm
```

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'ten/add/$', TenCreate.as_view(), name='ten_create'),
    url(r'update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TenUpdate.as_view(), name='tender_update'),
    url(r'delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TenDelete.as_view(), name='tender_delete'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TenDetail.as_view(), name='ten_detail'),
    url(r'add_part/$', AddPart.as_view(), name='part_create'),
    url(r'update_part/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', UpdatePart.as_view(), name='part_update'),]
```

Here is my related forms.py class:

```
class EditPartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ['part_name', 'part_description', 'ten']
```

And here is my template:

```
<h1>Update a New Part</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update Part">
 </form>
```

Edit: Here is the models.py for the two relevant classes:

```
class Ten(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ten_name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.create_date <= now

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('maketen:ten_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'create_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

    ten_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')


class Part(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
         return self.part_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('maketen:ten_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.ten.pk})

    ten = models.ForeignKey(Ten)
    part_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    part_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
```

I have a similar class that uses UpdateView (TenUpdate) and it works perfectly, however, UpdatePart generates a 405 error.

I know 405 is a post error, but I don't understand why.  I reviewed all the related questions I could find as well as the docs but they mostly relate to function based views. Plus, reading things you don't yet understand doesn't help much :)

My gut feel is that it has something to do with urls, but I can't say that for sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that your full urls? Can you show the full traceback? It will show whether it is the `UpdateView` which is throwing the 405 error (which would be surprising), or if another view is handling the request because of a problem in your urls.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you don't get a traceback on a 405 response. I agree with your suggestion that it might be a problem in the urls.py, but I haven't spotted any problems with what you've posted.

Comment: @Alasdair I am still in the very early stages of building the site, so there isn't much to show!  But yes, there is no traceback as you said, just the console giving the error and a blank template.

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to check the URL that the POST request is submitted to, and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: @Alasdair I checked and it seems fine.  I use a button to call the UpdateView and in the template it generates `action="/maketen/update_part/24/" ` where 24 is the pk of the Part that must be edited.  

My expectation is that the button will pass the pk to the class which will then do the magic that UpdateView does.  With UpdateTen it works like a charm.  So it _looks_ right but no dice.  I added the models to the question in case it reveals something.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure out what the problem is!

Comment: Since you mentioned the URL starts with "maketen", that implies that the urls.py you've shown is included from a top-level urls file. Can you show that one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sure `'urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^maketen/', include('maketen.urls', namespace="maketen")),
    url(r'^equate/', include('equate.urls', namespace="equate")),
]`

The rest of the app works well though, so it is just this issue I am severely stuck with.

Comment: In an effort to try and catch the exception I ended up using the get_object method instead of passing the object id through the url (as expalined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561736/django-updateview-without-pk-in-url.  This raises a DoesNotExist error and indicates that pk=None - I am making the assumption that the same error happens when I simply pass the pk along.  It still doesn't solve the problem because I don't see why the object isn't loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the POST to the same pk:
in your template:

```
<h1>Update a New Part</h1>

<form action="{% url 'part_update' pk=object.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update Part">
 </form>
```

same happened to me, this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, this has been a long time ago and learned that same lesson.  I'll mark as the correct answer.