# Django UpdateView pk via POST arguments

Tags: django, django-views

I'm developing an app on django v1.10, and I want to pass a **pk** to an **UpdateView** (CBV) via **POST** arguments for security reasons, because the app uses an authentication system.

I've researched and found that overriding the **get_object** method I (should) get what I want but nothing happens. ([Django UpdateView without pk in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561736/django-updateview-without-pk-in-url))

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or I'm missing something. Maybe the situation requires a different approach.

In my template **source of the link** (not the UpdateView template) I pass the argument via link in a form, **calification.id** is the pk.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'edu:calification-update' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" value="{{ calification.id }}" name="pk">
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">editar</button>
</form>
```

In the receiving view I override the **get_object** method:

```
class CalificationUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Calification
    template_name = 'edu/calification_create.html'
    form_class = CalificationForm

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Calification, pk=self.request.POST.get('pk'))
        return obj
```

In my ModelForm:

```
class CalificationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Calification
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my **edu/calification_create.html**:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success snps-btn-save form-control" value="Guardar" />
</form>
```

But in the update view the object is not retrieved, the form is in blank and no error appears.

I checked that POST parameters are passed OK, there is no problem with template object, **calification.id** is declared fine, it's like the **get_object** method doesn't retrieve the instance.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you print `self.request.POST.get('pk')` in the `get_object` method.

Comment: @Alasdair I get the value of the pk (i.e. **1**).

Comment: Your `get_object` method looks ok then. It's not really clear what the problem is. Why do you use the create template `edu/calification_create.html` for an update view.

Comment: The **edu/calification_create.html** has a standard django template code of a form.

    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success snps-btn-save form-control" value="Guardar" />
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

The default template context name for the object to update is `object`. If you use something else you need to specify it with `context_object_name`.

Comment: I'm sorry @Tomas Walch, I don't understand your answer. As far as i've researched, in CBV to retrieve the desired instance with other args than pk, you must override the get_object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object

"Returns the single object that this view will display."

Comment: As far as I can see that is not your problem. Your problem is that you reference `calification` in your template. There is no such variable, the object returned from `get_object` is by default called `object`.

Comment: Now I understand your answer. Its not a problem with the template object, it is renamed. I edited the question to clarify that the param pk is rendered and passed OK. I tried the same thing but using GET, and the result is the same no object is found.

Comment: In the code samples you have shown you are not setting the value of `calification` anywhere. Just saying.

Comment: It's declared in awfully large piece of code (in a forloop), I omitted it for simplicity.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with your `get_object`. As you are not getting a 404 then your error lies in how you reference the object in the template. If this is the entire view class.

Comment: Yes, it is. I simplified the form template to the barebone also, and I get the same result.

Comment: So how are you referencing the object in the template ( i e how is `calification` set? Because it is not set in the view code) 
And what happens if you add `context_object_name='calification'` to the view class?

Comment: In my previous comment I referenced the **form** template, which is the UpdateView template. There the object form is referenced by the `{{ form }}` tag. The template source of the link (where there is `calification.id`) has no problem, the object there is well declared despite I don't show the code, because it's a large template code.

Comment: So you are quoting template code that is working, and not the code where you have problems? Why?

Comment: I show the code that I think exposes the process, not the code that "has no problems", because, In fact, I don't know where the problem is. But it is NOT in the template object I called `calification`. The pk is there. The form/link passes the post parameters with the pk. The problem is the UpdateView, the receiving object.

Comment: I thought that template was the template used by the update view. You need to show that template. If `pk` is sent to the view and `get_object` isn't raising 404 then the error is in the update view template

Comment: As I answered above to Alasdair, `self.request.POST.get('pk')` in the `get_object` method prints the pk of the object.

Comment: I'm using the standard example django code for forms to avoid other issues <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success snps-btn-save form-control" value="Guardar" />
</form>

Comment: What does the form class look like then?

Comment: I updated the question with both ModelForm and form (create) template. I changed them to be as simple as I could think.

Comment: Have you run through a request in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You must modify the "get_object" method, capture the value of the parameter you are passing by replacing the line that says:

```
pk = self.kwargs.get (self.pk_url_kwarg)
```

by:

```
if self.request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid ():
            pk = form.pk
```

This works for me