# Checking current user against page they are looking at

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check the currently logged in user against the user who created the page they are looking at. So essentially, if I am logged in I shouldn't able to go to another user's posts/profile and be able to edit it simply by typing in the edit url pattern.

Here is my view:

```
class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = UserProfile
    fields = [
            'first_name',
            'profile_pic',
            'location',
            'title',
            'user_type',
            'about',
            'website',
            'twitter',
            'dribbble',
            'github'
            ]
    template_name_suffix = '_edit_form'

    def qet_queryset(self,request):
        current_user = request.user.id
        url_args = request.resolver_match.kwargs.pk

        if current_user != url_args:
            reverse('index')
```

I have the `get_queryset` function and the if statement inside it to check if the currently logged in user is the owner of the profile they are trying to edit and redirect them if they aren't. However it is not doing anything... How do I go about implementing this?

**Update**

View:

```
class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = 'users/userprofile_edit_form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)

    def get_success_url(self):
        userid = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse_lazy('users:user_profile',kwargs={'pk': userid})
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.UserListView.as_view(),name='user_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.detailprofile,name='user_profile'),
#   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$',views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),name='user_profile_edit'),
    url(
    regex=r'^profile/$',
    view=views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),
    name='profile'
),
]
```

**Update 2**

Userprofile_detail.html Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="sidebar-userinfo">
        {% if user.userprofile.profile_pic %}
            <img class="profile-pic" src="{{ user.userprofile.profile_pic.url }}">
        {% else %}
            <img class="profile-pic" src="../../../media/profile_pics/default_pro_pic.png">
        {%endif%}

        <div class="profile-top-info">
            <h2 class="profile-name">{{ user.userprofile.first_name }}</h2>
            {% if user.userprofile.location %}
                <p class="profile-info small-text">{{ user.userprofile.location }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="profile-info-group">
            <p class="accent list-text">Title:</p>
            <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.title }}</p>

            <p class="accent list-text">Website:</p>
            <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.website }}</p>

            <p class="accent list-text">I'm a:</p>
            {% if user.userprofile.user_type == '1' %}
                <p class="profile-info list-text">Designer</p>
            {% elif user.userprofile.user_type == '2' %}
                <p class="profile-info list-text">Developer</p>
            {% else %}
                <p class="profile-info list-text">Both</p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if user.userprofile.about %}
                <p class="accent list-text">About Me:</p>
                <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.about }}</p>
            {% endif %}

            <p class="accent list-text">Member Since:</p>
            <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.join_date }}</p>

            {% if user.userprofile.twitter %}
                <p class="accent list-text">Twitter:</p>
                <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.twitter }}</p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if user.userprofile.dribbble %}
                <p class="accent list-text">Dribbble:</p>
                <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.dribbble }}</p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if user.userprofile.github %}
                <p class="accent list-text">Git Hub:</p>
                <p class="profile-info list-text">{{ user.userprofile.github }}</p>
            {% endif %}

        </div>

        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile_edit' %}">Edit Profile</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="content-right">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="btn float-right" href="{% url 'feed:new_post' %}">New Post</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% include 'feed/userpost_list_inner.html' %}
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

User profile_edit_form.html template:

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="form-title">
        <h2 class="form-title-text">Edit Profile</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="user-forms-base">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sam Bobel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3598519/sam-bobel) is right and here is the solution in code for the profile problem:

`forms.py`:

```
class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'profile_pic',
            'location',
            'title',
            'user_type',
            'about',
            'website',
            'twitter',
            'dribbble',
            'github'
        ]
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        regex=r'^profile/$',
        view=views.UserEditProfileView.as_view(),
        name='profile'
    ),
]
```

`views.py`:

```
class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = 'users/userprofile_edit_form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        # Only get the User record for the user making the request
        return User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
```

Comment: So you're saying I should change my view to what you've put here? What about the url pattern, I saw you removed that?

Comment: Ok, so I think I got it? But it now just returns a blank edit profile form instead of the one with the currently logged in user's info... I Updated the question to show what I did.

Comment: Hi Garrett, I updated my post to make it a bit more verbose. It seems that you are missing a proper ModelForm definition. Give it a try. Why are you defining the attribute login_url in your view?

Comment: I did have `ModelForm` defined in the form, but it still isn't working... I have the `login_url` in the view because it has `LoginRequiredMixin` so I specified where it should the user to login. I was following a tutorial that had did that.

Comment: Add the html template to your original post. So that I can test it by myself.

Comment: Just added it. I am still using the names I had originally set in the url.

Comment: Mhh, the user profile edit template perfectly works for me. Are you still setting the model attribute directly in your view, which isn't correct? The code I have posted works for me and renders the {{ form.as_p }} as expected.

Comment: I removed the model attribute from the view to match what you've shown here and it still doesn't work...

Comment: The next step would be to debug the parameters your view renders to the template. I would delete all content of your template and make sure that you can successfully render some static HTML. After that add {% debug %} to the template and look if the form tag is available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155871/discussion-between-yannic-hamann-and-garrett).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a slightly different way. You really don't want those URLs to even exist, because you don't want to tempt the user into changing the number. Instead, I would not pass a PK into the URL at all, and just fetch the current user through overwriting the `get_object` method to use `request.user.id`.

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561736/django-updateview-without-pk-in-url) for more info

Let me know if clarification would help

Comment: Ok, so I think I got it? But it now just returns a blank edit profile form instead of the one with the currently logged in user's info... I Updated the question to show what I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator for this. `

```
def your_decorator(view_func):
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        .....do your conditions here...if fail redirection takes place here
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

return wrapped
```

Just use the decorator and it is that simple.