# I created a form to let me edit my user and email(using Python, Django, and Vue.js). When I press submit changes, nothing happens

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, vue.js

So I am working on this time tracking app for myself, to learn Django and Vue.js, I found a tutorial from Code with Stein. I got stuck at editing the profile part from the tutorial. I get no errors, yet there are no changes made to my username or email(the changes don't even apply to my admin dashboard or database). The thing is that I get no error, which leaves me completely in the dust.

Here is the code in edit_profile.html:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Edit Profile | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <nav class="breadcrumb" aria-label="breadcrumbs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'myaccount' %}">My Account</a></li>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}" aria-current="page"></a>Edit Profile</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-4">
            <h1 class="title">Edit Profile</h1>

            <form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input"{% if request.user.username %} value="{{ request.user.username }}" {% endif %}>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input"{% if request.user.email %} value="{{ request.user.email }}" {% endif %}>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Password(You can change it if you want it.)</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input"{% if request.user.password %} value="{{ request.user.password }}" {% endif %}>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-success">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the code in my views.py:

```
#
#

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


#
# Import models

from .models import Userprofile

#
# Views

@login_required
def myaccount(request):
    return render(request, 'userprofile/myaccount.html')

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.user.username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        request.user.email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        request.user.password = request.POST.get('password', )
        request.user.save()

        messages.info(request, 'The changes were saved!')

        return redirect('myaccount')
    
    return render(request, 'userprofile/edit_profile.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.email = user.email
            user.save()

            userprofile = Userprofile.objects.create(user=user)

            login(request, user)

            return redirect('frontpage')
    
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'userprofile/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

So I tried to add an input for the username in my signup.html form, and then implementing it to the vue.js part of the code, aswell as in my views.py, thinking that maybe I should elaborate more to the syntax, but it seems that doesn't work. When I tried to use that modified version, I would've get a lot of errors, and it wouldn't create me an username, so I dropped that, undid it to the initial code, told myself to try find a solution on stackoverflow.

p.s chatgpt doesn't have the fix either

So what I am looking, is to change the username and email from the "my account" dashboard, without logging in into the admin panel. [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wCsCIg1cAk&list=PLpyspNLjzwBkm7Y28Gma4F9hl2wpuypgp&index=9) at minute 40:38 is how the code is supposed to work.

Comment: You should try [Django UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), by doing so, your form doesn't need to manually validating it by adding `maxlength=specify-numbers`, take a look at an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181041/updating-user-model-in-django-with-class-based-updateview)

Comment: yeah, the thing is that I use Vue script for the signup.html , if it was only django, I wouldn't have this issue, probably.